# MVC3.NET controller not including arrays in result?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3

in an MVC controller does this.JSON not include arrays? For example I have:

```
{
    result: true,
    tags: [
        {
            name: tag1,
            values: [
                {id: 1, value: "troy"},
                {id: 2, value: "Corey"}
            ]
        }
        {
            name: tag2,
            values: [
                {id: 1, value: "Nikki"},
                {id: 2, value: "Scoob"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But the values array is always coming back empty. When I step through, the object I am passing has a count of 5 for the values IList

Calling:

```
return this.Json(dh.GetTags(companyId, categoryId), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but you don't have valid JSON in the question.

Comment: I just typed it up quickly to show the output format/structure I am expecting. The result of dh.GetTags is an object that this.Json converts to JSON